# How to view an image with matplotlib when using requests.get(image_url)

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-requests

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
r = requests.get('https://checkimage.etest.net.cn/65DE0E55A627E56EAA0FA6F8198D2A43.jpg')
```

How can I use `r.text` to show the image directly and what kind of encoding it is?

Answer (score 7):

As the [request documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) states:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

i = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
```

So in your case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

r = requests.get('https://checkimage.etest.net.cn/65DE0E55A627E56EAA0FA6F8198D2A43.jpg')

im = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))

plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```